# How to give custom implementation of UpdateAsync method of asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I am doing custom asp.net identity and not using asp.net inbuilt tables.I have successfully created user with implementing custom `CreateAsync`

Now i want to update user with new encrypted password and so i am not getting how to provide custom implementation of `UpdateAsync method`.

This is my table:

**User** : `Id,Name,EmailId,Password,Statistics,Salary`

**Model**:

```
public class UserModel : IUser 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }  
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}
```

**My custom class which implements IUserstore:**

```
public class UserStore : IUserStore<UserModel>, IUserPasswordStore<UserModel>
{
    private readonly MyEntities _dbContext;
    private readonly HttpContext _httpContext;

    // How to implement this method for updating only user password
    public Task UpdateAsync(UserModel user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(UserModel user)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HttpContext.Current = _httpContext ?? HttpContext.Current;
                var user = _dbContext.User.Create();
                user.Name = user.Name;
                user.EmailId = user.EmailId;
                user.EmailAddress = user.Email;
                user.Password = user.Password;
               _dbContext.Users.Add(dbUser);
               _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            });
    }

    public Task SetPasswordHashAsync(UserModel user, string passwordHash)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                HttpContext.Current = _httpContext ?? HttpContext.Current;
                var userObj = GetUserObj(user);
                if (userObj != null)
                {
                    userObj.Password = passwordHash;
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                    user.Password = passwordHash;
            });
    }

    public Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(UserModel user)
    { 
        //other code
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class MyController : ParentController
{
    public MyController()
        : this(new UserManager<UserModel>(new UserStore(new MyEntities())))
    {
    }

    public UserManager<UserModel> UserManager { get; private set; }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> SaveUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        IdentityResult result = null;
        if (userModel.Id > 0) //want to update user with new encrypted password
            result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        else
            result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(userModel.EmailId, userModel.Password);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` to push the method onto a background thread seems like a bad idea. Either mark the methods as `async` and use `await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`, or make the methods synchronous and return `Task.FromResult(true);` at the end.

Comment: @richard deeming thank you so much for very nice suggestion.i really appreciate it.sometimes I am facing problem like when I debug this code  then call never return back.is it because of this task.factory.new??

Comment: Possibly. And even if it's not, removing the `Task.Factory.StartNew` might make it easier to see the error.

Comment: You've also got a variable naming conflict in `CreateAsync`: the `user` variable defined within the `Task.Factory.StartNew` delegate hides the `user` parameter. But I suspect that's just a typo in your question, as you then use an undefined variable called `dbUser`. :)

Comment: @richard deeming yeah that is just a typing mistake.apart from this can you suggest me something about implementation of updateasync please??

Comment: I'd avoid touching the password in the `UpdateAsync` method - AFAIK, that's only for updating *other* properties. The `SetPasswordHashAsync` method is used to update the password.

Comment: @Richard Deeming I am updating user and during this update user will enter his new password and then simply I will overwwrite this new password with the old password.so how do I call this method setpasswordhash for encrypting my password for update process.can you please guide me a little

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37866098/124386

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122533/discussion-between-learning-and-richard-deeming).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what your looking for...

```cs
public Task UpdateAsync(UserModel model)
{
    var user = _dbContext.User.Find(x => x.id == model.id);
    user.Password = model.Password;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

It Will get the specific record and Update the password and then save the record.

**Edit**

Since the password is not getting encrypted i added code to take that string and leave the model as it is, this extension method will encrypt the value of password, i have not test this but i am sure it will work.

```
 user.Password = model.Password.EncryptPassword(EncryptKey);
```

[Extension methods to encrypt password](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2791259/6503942)

Comment: you can save any value from your model.

Comment: But here my question is will the password will be encrypted by Microsoft identity and saved in database or my password will be saved in plain text??

Comment: This will Save the value that is inside the model.

Comment: in your Save user method i would do the user id check then do the password conversion and then send that model to your update method.

Comment: Yeah but my password will be hashed??

Comment: Sorry but my new password is not getting encryted

Comment: @Learning you should create an extension method to encrypt the password. you can use it inside the code of the UpdateAsync. Do you want me toexplain with code? model.Password.ChangePassword(hashsymbol) somethinglike that

Answer (score 0):

Sometime back, I created a complete wrapper over .NET Identity and code can be found [here](https://github.com/techygarg/CodeNode.Identity/blob/master/CodeNode.Identity/IdentityManager.cs). It might be helpful for you. You can also find nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeNode.Identity/). I also explained the library in a blog [here](http://%20www.codingeek.com/dotnet/codenode-identity-an-implementation-of-asp-net-identity).